# file protocol of SVN with Android Studio

Tags: svn, android-studio, tortoisesvn

When I expand below URL

```
file:///D:/dev/admin/subversion/dev707/hello-android
```

in Android Studio (1.1.0) I get following error

```
svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
```

Though, I can browse the same URL using TortoiseSVN 1.8.11 and Eclipse 4.4.2.

Please explain how to access SVN repo in Android Studio using file protocol.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create backward compatible SVN repo using new Tortoise SVN:-

1. By default, Tortoise SVN does not install 'svn command line client tools'. Re-install Tortoise SVN with 'commnad line client tools'.

[image: Tortoise Installation]

2. Update Settings --> Version Control --> Subversion --> General as shown below. Also restart Android Studio, so it will pick up new PATH environment variable recently set by Tortoise SVN re-installation.

[image: Android Studio Settings]

3. Create backward compatible SVN repository using below command with Tortoise SVN 1.8.11.

   `svnadmin create --compatible-version 1.7 studio`
4. Now, add SVN URL to Android Studio, you will be able to access the SVN content.

[image: Android Studio SVN Repos]

Comment: As far as I recall, Android Studio supports Subversion 1.7, therefore you can use `--compatible-version 1.7` option.

Comment: @bahrep Yes, you are right. --compatible-version 1.7 works with Android Studio 1.1.0. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better install Subversion server instead of accessing a repository via `file://` access scheme. When accessing a repository via HTTP(S) or svnserve it does not matter what repository format version is.

Moreover, when you access the repository via `file://`, you access it directly on disk. Therefore there is no authentication and authorization, no hook scripts work, you can't make the repository available for other developers, etc.